# Offline form submission options

Tags: vba, offlineapps

We are building a web application that, given some basic information, facilitates the automatic creation of products and product items. This is an iterative process.

Some of our user groups do not have a reliable network connection, causing a need for offline form submission. This form should allow to select values of a predefined list, as well as filling in some basic fields. Our client is not fond of the idea of offline web applications (*"You still need your browser"*), so we had a look at Adobe's Interactive PDFs but as it might be hard to generate this kind of PDFs we're not convinced just yet. Another option would be VBA-equipped Word documents, but we fear these would not be very user-proof.

Are there any other options and/or experiences to share?

Comment: Unless you specify your requirements this will result in a very broad discussion. For example: you mentioned that you want it to be user-proof. What do you mean by that? Also, when you are stating that you want to develop an offline tool you also need to specify how / when / who will submit the values from the offline tool. For example: if you consider Excel / Word as offline tool, do you expect users to send afterwards Word / Excel files by email to you or would you allow the Excel (offline) tool to connect (upon request) online to the server to upload the results. Just to note two things....

Comment: We're really open for all options, so we're searching for similar cases. There are no requirements (yet). With user-proof documents I mean documents that can only be modified where it is allowed, so they remain parseable.